# Yii2 выборка из БД + если находит id в БД должен не проходить, но почему-то проходит

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

```
$model = new FormUnosh();

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $sql = 'SELECT NagrNomer FROM FormUnosh';
    $provg = FormUnosh::findBySql($sql)->all();
    if($provg){
        foreach ($provg as $item){
            if ($model->NagrNomer!=$provg){
                $model->save();
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException('Не верно!');
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
} else {
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: что значит должен проходить? если это условие то добавьте его в метод findbysql. а сейчас у вас в модели вся таблица (много строк поэтому не ясно какой id вы запрашиваете), а должна быть всего одна запись с одним id.

Comment: я имел ввиду то, что во время добавления записи он получает данные NagrNomer, и если во время добавления записи он находит уже данное число он выдает ошибку.

Comment: и соответсвенно запись не добавляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятно вообще ваша логика, что вы делаете, но судя по всему вам лучше вот так написать:

```
$model = new FormUnosh();

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $isInBD = FormUnosh::find()->where(['NagrNomer' => $model->NagrNomer])->count();
    if ($isInBD > 0) {
        $model->save();
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Не верно!');
    }

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
}

return $this->render('create', [
    'model' => $model,
]);
```

А вообще лучше это вынести в модель в валидатор. А ещё лучше подумать над логикой приложения - по-моему что-то хромает у вас в ней.

Comment: Забыл отписаться решил такой-же конструкцией, но все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых можно сразу писать в sql условие where и не тянуть все записи из БД. Пока у Вас их мало, все нормально. Но когда у Вас их будет миллион и тысяча пользователей к ней обратится, Ваш код рухнет как карточный домик.

Во-вторых, логика приложения неправильная, вот смотрите.

```
foreach ($provg as $item){
  if ($model->NagrNomer!=$provg){
    $model->save();
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
  } else {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException('Не верно!');
  }
}
```

Вопрос, что случится, когда код достигнет return? Ответ - он выйдет из цикла сохранив изменения. Поэтому данный код возьмет самый первый элемент, тут упрется в return и никакой итерации по всем товарам не случится.